# Delete rows from table depending on previous value

Tags: sql, mariadb, mariasql

I have data set that looks like this:

| internal_id | match_id | company_id | market_id | selection_id | odd_value | update_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8576748 | 66 | 1 | 1 | 1.31 | 2021-01-05 17:59:41 |
| 36730 | 8576748 | 66 | 1 | 1 | 1.30 | 2021-01-05 18:58:41 |
| 47053 | 8576748 | 66 | 1 | 1 | 1.31 | 2021-01-05 19:59:41 |
| 2 | 8576748 | 66 | 1 | 2 | 14.00 | 2021-01-05 17:59:41 |
| 36731 | 8576748 | 66 | 1 | 2 | 14.00 | 2021-01-05 18:58:41 |
| 47054 | 8576748 | 66 | 1 | 2 | 14.00 | 2021-01-05 19:59:41 |
| 3 | 8576748 | 66 | 1 | 3 | 3.75 | 2021-01-05 17:59:41 |
| 36732 | 8576748 | 66 | 1 | 3 | 3.75 | 2021-01-05 18:58:41 |
| 47055 | 8576748 | 66 | 1 | 3 | 3.75 | 2021-01-05 19:59:41 |

I need to delete rows in which previous odd_value for the same match_id+company_id+market_id+selection_id is the same. In this example rows with internal_id: 36731, 47054, 36732, 47055 should be deleted.

As you can see it's not a duplication deletion, rows 1 and 47053 are the same (for match_id+company_id+market_id+selection_id), but they should remain as they are because odd_value 1,30 (for internal_id 36730) is different than previous odd_value and odd_value 1,31 (for internal_id 47053) is different than previous odd_value.

To list this data I used this query:

```
SELECT
    `internal_id`,
    `match_id`,
    `company_id`,
    `market_id`,
    `selection_id`,
    `odd_value`,
    `update_date`
    
FROM
    `odds`
WHERE
    `match_id` = 8576748
    AND `company_id` = 66
ORDER BY `match_id`, `company_id`, `market_id`, `selection_id`, `update_date`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is how you can distinguish rows you want to delete and write the delete statement the same way :

```
SELECT *
  ,CASE WHEN LAG(odd_value) OVER (PARTITION BY match_id, company_id , market_id,selection_id ORDER BY update_date) = odd_value THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS tobeDeleted 
FROM `odds`
```

Comment: can You please help me out also with delete.
I have this query:
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        *,
        CASE WHEN LAG(odd_value) OVER(
        PARTITION BY match_id,
        company_id,
        market_id,
        selection_id
    ORDER BY
        update_date
    ) = odd_value THEN 1 ELSE 0
END AS duplikat
FROM
    `odds`
ORDER BY
    `match_id`,
    `company_id`,
    `market_id`,
    `selection_id`,
    `update_date`
) 
AS innerTable
WHERE
    duplikat = 1

but can't make proper DELETE, I tried with WHERE internal_id IN but it doesn't work

Comment: I think I managed with this:
DELETE FROM `odds` WHERE `internal_id` IN 
(SELECT
    `internal_id`
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        *,
        CASE WHEN LAG(odd_value) OVER(
        PARTITION BY match_id,
        company_id,
        market_id,
        selection_id
    ORDER BY
        update_date
    ) = odd_value THEN 1 ELSE 0
END AS duplikat
FROM
    `odds`
ORDER BY
    `match_id`,
    `company_id`,
    `market_id`,
    `selection_id`,
    `update_date`
) 
AS innerTable
WHERE
    duplikat = 1)